# Loop through list for send_keys (Selenium & Python)

Tags: python, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to loop through a list and then having the code click the search button, print the result and repeat. I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "qtest.py", line 17, in 
    list = [PR311, PR311, 5, 7, 9] 
NameError: name 'PR311' is not defined

This is my code:

```
    # Imports, of course
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Initialize a Firefox webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Grab the web page
driver.get("https://mnlairport.ph/terminal-finder")

# We use .find_element_by_id here because we know the id
text_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/div/input")

list = [PR311, PR3345, PR323, PR355, PR3987] 

# Using for loop 
for i in list: 

    # Then we'll fake typing into it
    text_input.send_keys(list)

    # Now we can grab the search button and click it
    search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/div/button")
    search_button.click()

    # We can feed that into Beautiful Soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    form = soup.find('div', class_= 'info-box')

    for post in form:
        print(post)
```

---

UPDATED CODE: Issue now is, it doesn't loop properly

```
    csv_file = open('test.csv', 'w')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['post'])

    list = ["PR311", "XC827", "KD271", "5J745", "SQ916"] 

    # Using for loop 
    for i in list: 

    # We use .find_element_by_id here because we know the id
        text_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'form-control')]")

        # Then we'll fake typing into it
        text_input.send_keys(i)

        # Now we can grab the search button and click it
        search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'search-btn')]")
        search_button.click()

        # We can feed that into Beautiful Soup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
        form = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'info-box'})

        for post in form:
            print(post)
            csv_writer.writerow([post.text])

         #Clear previous inputs
        text_input.clear()

    csv_file.close()

    # Close the webdriver
    driver.close()
```

I closed the loop by clearing the search bar but it skips through some in the list or doesn't return the right value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are string the elements in your list? Then replace with this, your code try to find a variable with that names

```
list = ["PR311", "PR3345", "PR323", "PR355", "PR3987"]
```

Also, you will have to get input element at start or end loop each time. And you will get problems with that Xpath definition

```
for i in list: 
    text_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'form-control')]")


    #Clear previous inputs
    text_input.clear()

    text_input.send_keys(i)

    search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'search-btn')]")
```

Comment: Thanks! That got it working. Now I'm trying to figure out how to delete an input before iteration. They all bundle together in one line...

Comment: Updated code (.clear() on element), mark as good answer if it helps you

Comment: made the changes you suggested on the code. (Posted updated code abovem it's working but loop skips and doesn't return right output)

Comment: Ups was a fault on my code, clear before send keys, I posted it after send_keys. Maybe you need a sleep time after send keys and after click on button to let website react

Comment: I had one sleep after clicking button. Added another, that did it.

Comment: Nice to hear that, thats cause python code runs faster than browser driver reacts